# integrity constraint violated - parent key not found when the value exists

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE TABLE Film
(
    idFilm        NUMBER         GENERATED BY DEFAULT as IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    titre         VARCHAR2(100)  NOT NULL,
    anneeDeSortie NUMBER(4)      NOT NULL,
    langueOrigine VARCHAR2(25),
    duree         Number(3)      NOT NULL,
    resume        VARCHAR2(600)  NOT NULL,
    affiche       VARCHAR2(2083),
    realisateur   number,
    constraint fk_idRealisateur
        FOREIGN KEY (realisateur) REFERENCES Personnalite (idPersonnalite)
);
```

That has the following row:

```
SELECT * FROM film where film.idfilm = 164184;
```

[image]

and when I try to add a row to the table `Scenariste`:

```
CREATE TABLE Scenariste
    (
    idScenariste  NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    nom           VARCHAR2(100)  NOT NULL,
    idFilm        NUMBER         NOT NULL,
    constraint fk_idScenariste
        FOREIGN KEY (idScenariste) REFERENCES Film (idFilm)
);

INSERT INTO scenariste (nom, idFilm) VALUES ('Paul Attanasio', 164184);
```

I get the following error:

```
Error starting at line : 3 in command -
INSERT INTO scenariste (nom, idFilm) VALUES ('Paul Attanasio', 164184)
Error report -
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (EQUIPE106.FK_IDSCENARISTE) violated - parent key not found
```

Why is this is happening if the film row with id `164184` actually exists?

Comment: I believe the FK constraint in `Scenariste` is defined wrong - you have `constraint fk_idScenariste FOREIGN KEY (idScenariste) REFERENCES Film (idFilm)` while I believe you want to link the `idFilm` (not `idScenariste`) in this FK reference....

Comment: you can not use idScenariste it mustbe idFilm as foreign ey

Comment: marc_s has your answer. However I would also add that if Scenariste is your screenwriter table (suggested further by the fact you have the writer's name (nom) in it), then are you really permitting a writer to write only one film? That's what your model suggests. You shuld probalby have a bridge table with keys to both scenariste and film so it can be a many to many. Or if a film can have only one writer, the scenariste link should be in film. Just guessing here based on your object names but something worth considering.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined your table with a wrong FK constraint.

You have:

```
CREATE TABLE Scenariste
(
    idScenariste  NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    nom           VARCHAR2(100)  NOT NULL,
    idFilm        NUMBER         NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_idScenariste
        FOREIGN KEY (idScenariste) REFERENCES Film (idFilm)
);
```

but I believe the FK constraint ought to be using the `idFilm` (not the `idScenariste` column):

```
    CONSTRAINT fk_idScenariste
        FOREIGN KEY (idFilm) REFERENCES Film (idFilm)
```